# Android - How to retrieve the google plus circles email addresses in android?

Tags: android, google-plus, social-networking

I am able to login with google plus and have fetched the list of all the people who are in my google plus circle but now i also want to get the email addresses of all people in my circle is there are way to do it?

Comment: Do you have an idea why the `this` code does not work?

Answer (score 0):

[plus.people.list](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/list) will only retrieve profile IDs for people in the currently authorized user's list. If you want contact information, you need to use the [Contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) or [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/).